# Command Brew not Found?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I installed homebrew with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`  on Mac but when I try to install python3 with

```
brew install python3
```

I get error of

```
zsh: command not found: brew
```

I know brew is installed but maybe I haven't done it in right location? I am in a directory of a folder in my desktop

Output of  `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'` ? One of the paths should be `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, Just added the output to post above

Comment: How can I change to that path?

Comment: @Chris90 did you source .your_bash file ?

Comment: @DRPK  not sure how to do that I just ran commands listed above of installing homebrew and then brew install python3

Comment: [zsh: command not found: brew](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3507)

Comment: (This is not a python/programming question, there may be a better place to put it)

Comment: Probably Brew is not completely installed in your shell yet. When you installed it, did it modify your `.zshrc` file? Can you show us those changes? Have you tried opening a new Terminal window; does it work there?

Comment: Try to run `find / -name "brew" -echo` and see what you get. Or you can try `update-db && locate brew`

Answer (score 1):

echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/neerajvishwa/.zprofile

type this in terminal - it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If using Macbook M1 chip run this after installation done

> eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

Answer (score 0):

I use the MacBook Air M1 and I have the same issue, where I need to run  `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)` every time I open the terminal to use brew.

I reran the 2 commands we are supposed to run after installing homebrew. (You need to replace [username] by your Mac user name)

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/[username]/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I even completely rebooted my Mac to make sure the fix was permanent.